# Content-Length maximum allowed length

Tags: ios, http, content-length

I'm programming in ObjectiveC. I guess that all oC programmers are using the rather standard code for posting:

```
NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:NO];
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[postData length]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
```

Currently I'm getting warning that NSUInteger should not be used as format argument.
The warning suggest a type cast (unsigned long). And also replacing %d with %lu. That sounds logical.

In the HTTP definition, I can not find how long the Content-Length may actually be. Just the rather vague Octet. Is that 8 bits? I can not find the answer!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no specific limit on the maximum value for the Content-Length.

https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.13

```
14.13 Content-Length
Any Content-Length greater than or equal to zero is a valid value.
```

Also the Apple documentation for `setValue:forHTTPHeaderField:` in the `NSMutableURLRequest` class reference states

> Additionally, if the length of your upload body data can be determined
>   automatically (for example, if you provide the body content with an
>   NSData object), then the value of Content-Length is set for you.

Answer (score -2):

This rfc sucks because it says that content-length must be a "decimal number" but it also says that it's a number of octets (so it can't be a decimal).

It depends on your implementation. 
For example in Java, max content-length is Integer.MAX_VALUE but, you can bypass it by reading the header directly (HTTP headers are strings).

There is no real HTTP limitation there.

Comment: It says "a decimal number of octets"; what's unclear about that?

Comment: A decimal number is not an Integer. So it cant be a number of Bytes

Comment: A "decimal" number is a number expressed in the decimal system.

Comment: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/07/NumberSetinR.svg

It s said it s expressed wit number of digit too. A number of digit is  a natural.

Comment: A "number of octets" by definition is an integer. Also, die ABNF does not allow any character other than 0..9.

Comment: "Decimal number" in this context means base-10. Compare this to HTTP chunk encoding, which uses a hexadecimal number (base 16).