# Change Content-Length limit

Tags: angular, apache

When I make a **http** get or **fetch** request using **Angular 6** on a **Apache PHP**  Server 
and the  **Content-Length** is over 5000 characters  I am getting these errors :

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http:/example.com/search/results/1' from
>   origin 'http://angular.localhost:7483' has been blocked by CORS
>   policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the
>   requested resource

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Response with status: 0  for URL:
>   null

but when the length is lower it doesn't show these errors.
Is this limit  constant or maybe I can change it ? 
The Content-Length I am refering to is the one on the image below 
[image]

Typescript code snipet on angular :

```
this.http.get(
SearchV2 + 'results/' + queryParams.join("/"),
{
    withCredentials: true
})
.map(res => res.json())
.toPromise();
```

Comment: Are you talking about payload length?

Comment: @UttamKumarMishra I add an image illustrating to which Content-Length I am referring to.

Comment: This question may already have an answer here- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22822826/content-length-maximum-allowed-length

Comment: @UttamKumarMishra I have seen almost every related question, but there is nothing which says something about the Angular Side. The content is delivered but angular shows that error, so it must be something with angular no ?

Comment: Please share the code...

Comment: @UttamKumarMishra I add the code.

Comment: I think this is related to apache not to angular, that is content-length property is just readonly AFAIK and you can not changed it's value on the client side. I dont have any knowledge on Apache but you should dig into that side not on the client side.

Comment: Yes, it is related to apache not to angular.